# Fill an empty value in R

Tags: r

I have 10 data files and I have created R code to process and extract information. I have used a subset condition in which the returned value stored in a variable X. My problem that for some data file, the subset condition returned nothing. Since I'm looping, I decided to store X value in a vector. My question , how do I fill or deal with `nothing` value. I tried `is.NULL` and `isTRUE` and they are not working.

Here is an example of the X value I'm getting:

```
X: 15.08751 
X: 16.09844 
X: 17.18453 
X: 18.09765 
X: 19.08647 
X: 20.10815 
X:
```

Then I store the values in vector `Xvalue<-c(Xvalue,X)`

I tried also:

```
if (X==""){
 X<-1000
 }
```

Does R have any built in way to deal with this issue. Any suggestions!!

Comment: what does `str(X)` show?

Comment: `X[X==""] <- 1000` or `X[is.null(X)] <- 1000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and I 'd like to share it with you . I downloaded a package called `gtools` and I used `invalid function`.

I have used the following condition:

```
if (invalid(X)){
     X<-value
 }
```